# Emberjs easyForm select set value

Tags: forms, ember.js

Im trying to preselect a select box with easyForm. https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm

I made a JsBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EveQOke/64/edit

I made everything like in documentation written https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm#usage, but without luck. Maybe someone can point out what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced `selection="country"` with `value="country"`. That seems to work. [Here is the working demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EveQOke/66/edit)